# background-color on split text in same element

Tags: html, css, text

Im trying to make this effect on a site im working on:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuYjh.jpg)

HTML:

```
<h1 class="bigHeadline">Trendy lobby og business center i Københavns centrum</h1>
```

CSS:

```
padding: 3px 0 0;
font-size: 44px;
line-height: 57px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline;
-webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7), -15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7), -15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
color: #fff;
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 200;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

i need the text to always be close (remove the un-colored stroke between), but if i try and correct it with line-height then it breaks on resize and/or other browsers.

Comment: I've set `line-height: 55px` and it works fine when resizing in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

here my solution :

CSS:

```css
#bigHeadline {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;  
  margin: 0 4vw;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);  
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 200;  
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7), -15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  box-shadow: 15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7), -15px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="bigHeadline">
  Trendy lobby og business center 
</h1>

<h1 id="bigHeadline">
  I Københavns centrum
</h1>
```

I have separate the text into two h1 this way you can control the two pieces of text more easly.
I've also use a display: inline-block, this way the two pieces of text will always be one above the other (the "block" part), but since the background should just cover the text, you need the "inline" part

Comment: the problem with this solution it that we get that large black area after the text